# Can I modify values as I classify a Perl 6 list?

Tags: list, hash, raku

The [List.classify](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List#routine_classify) method can transform a list into a hash by some mapping that I define. The result of that mapping is the hash key and the original value

```
my @list = (
    <Camelia 5>,
    <Camelia 6>,
    <Camelia 7>,
    <Amelia 1>,
    <Amelia 2>,
    <Amelia 3>
    );

my %hash = @list.classify: *.[0];

say %hash;
```

The hash values are lists of lists because the original thinygs it classified were lists:

```
{
Amelia => [(Amelia 1) (Amelia 2) (Amelia 3)],
Camelia => [(Camelia 5) (Camelia 6) (Camelia 7)]
}
```

But, I'd really want this:

```
{
Amelia => ( 1 2 3 ),
Camelia => ( 5 6 7 )
}
```

I could do some extra work, but that seems a bit too much work:

```
my @list = (
    <Camelia 5>,
    <Camelia 6>,
    <Camelia 7>,
    <Amelia 1>,
    <Amelia 2>,
    <Amelia 3>
    );

my %hash = @list
    .classify( *.[0] )
    .kv
    .map( {
        $^a => $^b.map: *.[*-1]
        } )
    ;

say %hash;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `:as` adverb:

```perl6
my @list = (
    <Camelia 5>,
    <Camelia 6>,
    <Camelia 7>,
    <Amelia 1>,
    <Amelia 2>,
    <Amelia 3>
    );

my %hash = @list.classify: *.[0], as => *.[1];

say %hash;  # {Amelia => [1 2 3], Camelia => [5 6 7]}
```

(Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be [documented](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List#routine_classify) yet.)

Comment: I knew there had to be something!

Answer (score 4):

There's another undocumented adverb `:into`, which I think is mostly there to be an adapter into `classify-list` in [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) (although something with "list" in the method name should be in [List](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List)):

```
my @list = (
    <Camelia 5>,
    <Camelia 6>,
    <Camelia 7>,
    <Amelia 1>,
    <Amelia 2>,
    <Amelia 3>
    );

@list.classify: *.[0], :into(my %hash), :as( *.[1] );

say %hash;
```

This form of it seems to make more sense, but this is also what you get when you don't use the `:into` adverb. I think there are two hashes in there:

```
 my %hash = Hash.new.classify-list: *.[0], @list, :as( *.[1] );
```